# Is there a way to bind an object DataGridColumn's to a cell and then reference different parts of the object for different things in that cell?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I couldn't think of a great way to word the title, so I'll do my best to describe what I'm actually going for below:

For my DataGrid, I have a list of row objects that have a list of cell objects (one for each column). In each cell, from the corresponding cell object, I want to display property_a, show property_b in a tooltip, and change the background color based on property_c.

The problem is I can't think of how I would go about binding the cell object to a cell template and then being able to reference the various properties. Any ideas?